# What can be inferred from this data?

Tags: probability, model

Suppose you ask 100 people, would you purchase this item for $1000?  You get responses that fall into one of three categories, Yes, No or Maybe.  Assuming you get a non-trivial number of each replies, can it be estimated what price would give an equal number of Yes's and No's (with the rest being Maybe's).  How would one model this?  Could it be determined with some assumptions?  What about with asking the question a second time with a different price?

This is hypothetical and not homework, and I can't seem to determine if there is anything that can be inferred.

Comment: You have only one price, so you have no information about how these proportions vary by price.

Comment: Taking the already expressed issues into account, you'd be looking at some kind of model with an ordered categorical response, though you'd probably want to treat the individuals' as random effects. It should be possible to estimate from such a model where the proportion of people (in your sampled population) saying 'yes' is equal to the proportion saying 'no', and give an interval for it.

Answer (score 1):

If the item is a box containing fifty-one \$20 bills, then most people will buy it. Bump the price up to \$1040, and most people will not buy it.

You can repeat the experiment with a price of \$1005, \$995, \$1010, \$990, but each time, you'll usually get 100% yes's. Any model built off these measurements will fail to correctly predict that at $1040, you'll get 100% no's. This illustrates that the information you get at even multiple prices may not be useful for predicting some other price.

Comment: That's a good point.  If you assume that it's a widget with no defined value (like money) does that change what is possible?  I'm thinking of a widget that lacks a good secondary market that can be used to verify prices, I guess like an non-liquid luxury item.

Answer (score 0):

As @gung stated, there is no variation in price so how would you be able to estimate what price would give an equal number of yes's and no's? Unless you were lucky (I guess) and had an equal number of yes's and no's when asking these 100 people at a price of $1000.

With that being said, there will be not be any variation in one's willingness to buy the item for $1,000 when the item is always a thousand dollars, and thus you would need to ask people if they would purchase the item at varying prices to even think about any type of modeling. You may also want to look into other factors, such as age, race, gender, SES, etc., to determine how these factors may or may not impact individuals' willingness to buy the item.

Comment: Suppose there were two or three prices with answers (all with a non-trivial number of each reply), is that enough for a rough model?  How many data points would you need?

Comment: Even with 2 or 3 prices, you would still not have enough variation. For example, if you had fifty cents and a thousand dollars as your two prices, it would be better to dichotomize your price variable (1 = one thousand dollars, 0 = fifty cents, or vice versa) as there is no information for if the price was one dollar or $100.00 (there are very large and distinct gaps between these price options) and there is no ability to distinguish price among these gaps with only two to three price options